# Win 10 WSL won't set default 2

Tags: windows, powershell

Completely new to developing on windows (as my mac is in for repair) and I'm trying to follow these instructions https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10

But while I seem to have an adequate version, my wsl does not seem to have the right option. I have installed the wsl update, but was not asked for elevated privaledges while doing so. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Can you try it unelevated?

Comment: Same error in a standard powershell

Comment: I've only ever done this on Windows 2004. I know they backported it to 1909 so haven't had much experience with that. Do you have any WSL distros installed? might be worth trying to convert one to WSL2 first before setting the default to see if any more errors show up `wsl --set-version <DistroName> 2`

Comment: OK, meanwhile im installing the version update (literally bought the computer this morning) and hope that will help

Comment: My mistake was running `wsl.exe --set-version Ubuntu 2` *inside* the Ubuntu distro I wanted to update. This did not throw an error but shut down the distro (no big surprise, really) and did nothing. Running `wsl --set-version Ubuntu 2` in the Windows powershell worked.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Make sure virtualisation is enabled in your BIOS by going to Task Manager -> More Details -> Performace -> CPU and an option called Virtualisation should be set to enabled. If it isn't enabled then go to your BIOS and enable **SVM Mode** on AMD CPUs or **Intel Virtualisation Technology** on Intel CPUs.

next, make sure WSL is enabled by running this in powershell:

```
dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux /all /norestart
```

and that the virtual machine feature is enabled by running this:

```
dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:VirtualMachinePlatform /all /norestart
```

Restart your computer. Then, go to the microsoft store and download your distro of choice. Then, set your default distro by running

```
wsl --setdefault <DistributionName>
```

and enable WSL 2 by running

```
wsl --set-default-version 2
```

again. If this doesn't work, run `wsl --help` and make sure `--set-default-version` is listed. If it isn't listed, your operating system does not support it and you need to update.  If it throws this error:

```
WSL 2 requires an update to its kernel component. For information please visit https://aka.ms/wsl2kernel
```

Update [here](https://aka.ms/wsl2kernel) and run the MSI update package.

Comment: He said he followed all of the steps in the article.. which he even linked. These are just steps from the article and not adding much else to this question imo

Comment: i guess you're right, i was just summing it up and helping them with the virtualisation thing if they haven't already enabled it.

Comment: i did all of this but it didn't work. i finally found a solution for it tho. run `wsl --update` and once it's onde restart by running `wsl --shotdown`

Comment: @MahanHazratiSagharchi, unfortunatelly, it doesn't work to me.

Comment: @RodrigoAraujo maybe try to redo the installation process step by step from the beginning. i did it in addition to what i commented. also make sure of WSL version. make sure you are installing v2.

Answer (score 16):

After following @ahsan-a's answer, make sure to complete the last step,[Set your distribution version to WSL 1 or WSL 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows/wsl/install-win10#set-your-distribution-version-to-wsl-1-or-wsl-2):

On Powershell:

```
wsl --list --verbose
```

Then:

```
wsl --set-version <distribution name> 2
```

Comment: Good catch, the answer from ahsan-a will only work for new installations, this handles existing ones. Also note that you'll need a lot of free space on your existing drive or the conversion will fail with errors like `Write to restore size failed`.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is stuck on this issue and they have tried the above solutions, I would give `wsl --set-version <distro_name> 2`.

Comment: This do the trick , i used this command  `wsl --set-version ubuntu 2`

Answer (score 1):

Step by step resolution for the issue.

Step 1: Make sure virtualization is enabled in your BIOS.

> Task Manager -> More Details -> Performance -> CPU -> Virtualization
> > -> "Enabled"

[image]

Step 2: Open "Windows Features" from start menu and make sure "Virtualization Machine Platform" and "Windows Subsystem for Linux" is checked

[image]

Step 3: From PowerShell, to see available distros in machine use

> wsl --list --verbose

[image]

Step 4: To set WSL default version to 2 use

> wsl --set-default-version 2

[image]

Step 5: To set the appropriate distro to wsl 2, use

> wsl --set-version  2

[image]

In case in Step 5, you encounter the error `WSL 2 requires an update to its kernel component`. Download and install MSI update package from [official MS site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual#step-4---download-the-linux-kernel-update-package). Once update is installed, restart and continue from step 4.

Answer (score 0):

Also @Simon H

I faced similar issue when updating to wsl2,
You may also keep both wsl1 and wsl2,
Once you have wsl1, Follow the guidelines as posted by @ahsan-a, update to wsl2

Have a new/separate linux distro installed for wsl2, Like this

[image]

Then you may easily switch between wsl1 and wsl2 like this

[image]

Observe the state, I just do start-> type the name of linux distro.

Next to make new distro default, Just supply as shown below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In some cases wsl2 doesn't work.

if your wsl machnine doesn't start deinstall your machine and set the default parameter to

```
wsl --set-default-version 1
```

and reinstall your wsl machine

Answer (score 0):

Make sure not to confuse

```
--set-default-version 2
```

with

```
--set-version <DistroName> 2
```

The first comand will only work, if you haven't explicitly set the distro to 1 before with the second command.

So in short, setting default version doesnt set current version.