# Win 10 WSL won't set default version to 2 with Ubuntu

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I have Windows 10 Pro Version 21H1 Build 19043.1052.
I have followed the guide in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/wsl/install-win10#step-4---download-the-linux-kernel-update-package and in [Win 10 WSL won't set default 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65004930/win-10-wsl-wont-set-default-2) to get wsl. And I want to upgrade to version 2. I installed the regular Ubuntu from the Microsoft app store. And I did `wsl --setdefault Ubuntu` followed by `wsl --set-default-version 2` and it only gave me `For information on key differences with WSL 2 please visit https://aka.ms/wsl2`. But `wsl -l -v` was still showing VERSION 1.

So I went an installed `Ubuntu-20.04 LTS` and now that version is showing VERSION 2 but not the regular `Ubuntu` one.

How can I get them both to version 2?

[image]

Comment: Did you try [this]?(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10). It suggests using the `--set-version` flag to upgrade a distribution to 2 ( or revert back to 1).

Comment: `wsl --set-version Ubuntu 2` works. even though the default distro is Ubuntu (see the star next to Ubuntu), `--set-default-version` does not work for it. that's odd.

Comment: `--set-default-version` is for future distro installations, not for converting existing distros. `--set-version` is the conversion command

Comment: could you put that as answer so i accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `--set-default-version`, you're setting the version for future distributions that you install. That doesn't convert or change any current distros you have installed. So for your existing `Ubuntu` distro that is version 1, you should use the `wsl --set-version` command to convert it to version 2 or revert back to version 1.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me (my Ubuntu version is 20.04)

```
wsl -l -v
wsl --set-version Ubuntu-20.04 2
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean `--set-version`?

Comment: Good catch, updated the answer to `--set-version`

Comment: Well that's better, but honestly, now it's just a duplicate of the already-accepted answer! :-)  I can't recall - As a new user, do you have the ability to "Edit"?  If so, I'd recommend adding your example of using the command to the already-accepted answer.  At least you can get 2 points of rep for the edit that way.

Comment: Hah, yes you're right! I tried to do that but my account doesn't have enough rep... I'll be adding to the accepted answers once that feature is unlocked.